# Advanced RecyclerView library - Expanded examples

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, expand

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

This seems to be a great library in terms of what functionality it offers. It has a "tutorial" on Expanded items, I tried with expand tutorial but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a working example or can anyone make a simple Use Case of expanding an item?

I found this question in stack overflow but this question answered for swipe example.

Please help me in expand's case

Comment: There is already one example is available https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/develop/example

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your recycler view as expandable, then please use this library. 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view and if you have any problem then please let me know.

Comment: Can you convert this tutorial to kotlin?